# Select Different Columns as a single result - MongoDB - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, select, multiple-columns

How do I select 'peerIP' and 'client_ip' as IP address. (DATA given below)

**I have gone this far.**

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->fields(array("payload.peerIP" => true, "payload.client_ip" => true, "payload.remote_host" => true, "payload.source" => true));
    foreach ($cursor as $document) {
        print_r($document['payload']);
    }
```

**which gives me:**

```
Array ( [remote_host] => 00.00.00.000 ) 
Array ( [peerIP] => 000.00.000.00 ) 
.......
Array ( [client_ip] => 00.000.00.00 )
```

**I am trying to achieve something like this:**

```
Array ( [peerIP] => 00.00.00.000 ) 
Array ( [peerIP] => 000.00.000.00 ) 
.......
Array ( [peerIP] => 00.000.00.00 )
```

*Any help? Is this even possible ?*

**DATA:**

```
Array ( 
    [session] => e283f2defa254228bb20527aeb334bf7 
    [peerIP] => 000.000.00.00 
    [commands] => Array ( ) 
        [loggedin] => [startTime] => 2015-07-29T11:45:46.685927 
        [ttylog] => [hostPort] => 22 [peerPort] => 52963 
        [version] => SSH-2.0-libssh2_1.6.0 
        [urls] => Array ( ) 
            [hostIP] => 127.0.0.1 
            [credentials] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( 
                        [0] => root [1] => root ) )
            [endTime] => 2015-07-29T11:45:49.976508 
            [unknownCommands] => Array ( ) ) 


Array ( [client_ip] => 000.00.000.00 
    [dist] => 23 [server_port] => 21 
    [timestamp] => 2015/07/31 02:41:04 
    [client_port] => 61447 
    [raw_sig] => 4:41+23:0:1400:63,0:mss,ws,sok,ts,eol+0::0 
    [params] => none 
    [server_ip] => 00.00.00.00
    [subject] => cli [os] => ??? [mod] => syn )
```

*PS: The values posted above are sys logs from different nodes, the outputs have different field names..*

Comment: Can't do that unless using aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Thank you, How do I go about that?

Comment: The following code will give me the result that I am trying to achieve. but I know it's not a great way to go about that. Is there a better way to get the results straight from the db so that I don't have to resort to this method?

Comment: Following code? I don't see any code

Comment: Gave a quick try at this using aggregation pipeline. No luck so far. Maybe it can't do that as well. Or I need more coffee. :)

Comment: `foreach ($cursor as $document) {
  // Finding Array Keys
  if (array_key_exists('peerIP', $document['payload'])): 
   $arrayKey = 'peerIP';
  elseif(array_key_exists('client_ip', $document['payload'])):
   $arrayKey = 'client_ip';
  elseif(array_key_exists('remote_host', $document['payload'])):
   $arrayKey = 'remote_host';
  elseif(array_key_exists('source', $document['payload'])):
   $arrayKey = 'source';
  endif;
  
  echo ($document['payload'][$arrayKey]);
  echo "<hr>";
 }`

Comment: sorry I couldn't figure out how to add code in to the comment  :)..

Comment: It's unreadable. Post it (well-formatted) to gist.github.com or something?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mubheer/73bd5f06397c978d07b1

Comment: Yeah, as of this moment, massaging data in the app is the only working solution I know about.

Comment: Thank you Sergio, I will wait if anyone has a suggestion..